# Fastest way to find which of two lists of columns of each row is true in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I'm looking for the fastest way to do the following:

We have a pd.DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'High': [1.3,1.2,1.1],
    'Low': [1.3,1.2,1.1],
    'High1': [1.1, 1.1, 1.1],
    'High2': [1.2, 1.2, 1.2],
    'High3': [1.3, 1.3, 1.3],
    'Low1': [1.3, 1.3, 1.3],
    'Low2': [1.2, 1.2, 1.2],
    'Low3': [1.1, 1.1, 1.1]})
```

That looks like:

```
In [4]: df
Out[4]:
   High  High1  High2  High3  Low  Low1  Low2  Low3
0   1.3    1.1    1.2    1.3  1.3   1.3   1.2   1.1
1   1.2    1.1    1.2    1.3  1.2   1.3   1.2   1.1
2   1.1    1.1    1.2    1.3  1.1   1.3   1.2   1.1
```

What I want to know is which one of the High1, High2, High3 float values is the first that is larger or equal to the High value. If there is none, it should be np.nan

And the same for the Low1, Low2, Low3 value, but in this case which one of them is the first that is lower or equal to the High value. If there is none, it should be np.nan

At the end I need to know which one, Low or High has come first.

One way to solve this is in a weird and not too performant way is:

```
df['LowIs'] = np.nan
df['HighIs'] = np.nan

for i in range(1,4):
    df['LowIs'] = np.where((np.isnan(df['LowIs'])) & (
        df['Low'] >= df['Low'+str(i)]), i, df['LowIs'])
    df['HighIs'] = np.where((np.isnan(df['HighIs'])) & (
        df['High'] <= df['High'+str(i)]), i, df['HighIs'])

df['IsFirst'] = np.where(
    df.LowIs < df.HighIs,
    'Low',
    np.where(df.LowIs > df.HighIs, 'High', 'None')
)
```

Which gives me:

```
In [8]: df
Out[8]:
   High  High1  High2  High3  Low  Low1  Low2  Low3  LowIs  HighIs IsFirst
0   1.3    1.1    1.2    1.3  1.3   1.3   1.2   1.1    1.0     3.0     Low
1   1.2    1.1    1.2    1.3  1.2   1.3   1.2   1.1    2.0     2.0    None
2   1.1    1.1    1.2    1.3  1.1   1.3   1.2   1.1    3.0     1.0    High
```

As I have to do this over and over again in many iterations where High/Low will be different, performance when doing this is key.

So I wouldn't mind if the High1, High2, High3 and Low1, Low2, Low3 would be in a separate DataFrame that is transposed or if it would be in a dict or whatever. So the process to prepare the data in whatever gives the best possible performance can be slow and awkward.

One solution I worked on but just couldn't get finished to work in a vectorized way and that also seems quite slow is:

```
df.loc[(df.index == 0), 'HighIs'] = np.where(
    df.loc[(df.index == 0), ['High1', 'High2', 'High3']] >= 1.3
)[1][0] + 1
```

So checking for which one of the columns it is true in that first row and then looking at the index number of np.where().

Looking forward to any suggestions and hope to learn something new! :)

Comment: Is this ultimately the problem you wish to solve or is this a problem you ran into in your solution to a different problem?  Just asking because this seems like a possible [x-y problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a vectorized approach with [`NumPy broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
a = df.values
out1 = (a[:,1:4] >= a[:,0,None]).argmax(1)+1
out2 = (a[:,5:8] <= a[:,4,None]).argmax(1)+1
df['LowIs'] = out2
df['HighIs'] = out1
df['IsFirst'] = np.where(out1!=out2,np.where(out1 > out2, 'Low', 'High'),None)
```

Sample output -

```
In [195]: df
Out[195]: 
   High  High1  High2  High3  Low  Low1  Low2  Low3  LowIs  HighIs IsFirst
0   1.3    1.1    1.2    1.3  1.3   1.3   1.2   1.1      1       3     Low
1   1.2    1.1    1.2    1.3  1.2   1.3   1.2   1.1      2       2    None
2   1.1    1.1    1.2    1.3  1.1   1.3   1.2   1.1      3       1    High
```

Comment: Thanks, this has been the best performing solution so far, being about 3 times faster than my approach! Maybe I should think about doing part of what I do just in numpy and leave pandas out...

Comment: @Marco That's the way to go! From my experience, when performing number crunching and looking for performance, NumPy is worth considering.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood the question right, this is a semi-vectorized version:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'High': [1.3,1.7,1.1],
    'Low': [1.3,1.2,1.1],
    'High1': [1.1, 1.1, 1.1],
    'High2': [1.2, 1.2, 1.2],
    'High3': [1.3, 1.3, 1.3],
    'Low1': [1.3, 1.3, 1.3],
    'Low2': [1.2, 1.2, 1.2],
    'Low3': [1.1, 1.1, 1.1]})

highs = ['High{:d}'.format(x) for x in range(0,4)]

for h in highs[::-1]:
    mask = df['High'] <= df[h]
    df.loc[mask, 'FirstHigh'] = h
```

Produces:

```
   High  High1  High2  High3  Low  Low1  Low2  Low3 FirstHigh
0   1.3    1.1    1.2    1.3  1.3   1.3   1.2   1.1     High3
1   1.7    1.1    1.2    1.3  1.2   1.3   1.2   1.1       NaN
2   1.1    1.1    1.2    1.3  1.1   1.3   1.2   1.1     High1
```

Explanation:
The key here is that we iterate over the columns in reverse. That is we start at `High3`, check if that is greater than `High`, and sets `FirstHigh` accordingly. Then we move on to `High2`. If this is also greater, we simply overwrite the previous result, if not it will simply stay as is. Since we iterate in this reverse order, the result is that the *first* column to be higher will end up as the final result.

Comment: I timed it, and your original version is slightly faster than mine. So just forget everything I wrote.

Comment: Yes, it works but it's slower. Still thanks for your input!

Answer (score 2):

Test your High-n columns against the High column:

```
a = df.iloc[:,1:4].ge(df.High, axis=0)

a
Out[67]: 
   High1  High2  High3
0  False  False   True
1  False  False  False
2   True   True   True
```

Now replace False with `np.nan` and ask for the column index of the min or max (it doesn't matter as all is True of np.nan):

```
a.replace(False, np.nan).idxmax(1)

0    High3
1      NaN
2    High1
```

Same principle for the Low columns with `le` as comparison operator.

Comment: Thanks, it works and is slightly faster than my approach, here's the final code I came up with:

<pre>
`a = df.iloc[:,1:4].rename(columns={'High1': 1, 'High2': 2, 'High3': 3}).ge(df.High, axis=0)`
`b = df.iloc[:,5:8].rename(columns={'Low1': 1, 'Low2': 2, 'Low3': 3}).le(df.Low, axis=0)`
`df['HighIs'] = a.replace(False, np.nan).idxmax(1)`
`df['LowIs'] = b.replace(False, np.nan).idxmax(1)`
`df['IsFirst'] = np.where(df.LowIs < df.HighIs, 'Low', np.where(df.LowIs > df.HighIs, 'High', 'None'))``